# The hash list function, hlist_add_before, implementation in Linxu kernel

Tags: hash, linux-kernel

The implementation for hash list function, hlist_add_before, in linux kernel is as below,

```
struct hlist_node {
    struct hlist_node *next, **pprev;
};

/*
 * This function is to add n before next
 */

static inline void hlist_add_before(struct hlist_node *n, struct hlist_node *next)
{
    n->pprev = next->pprev;
    n->next = next;
    next->pprev = &n->next;
    *(n->pprev) = n;
}
```

I am confused about the last line `*(n->pprev) = n` in the function.
I thought only the first three lines were enough.
How come the last line is there!!

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally.
It it just to place the last jigsaw puzzle piece in its place.
In this hash list function, it has to handle a triangle relationship.
First, cut off the original bonding, Second, insert the new one in between.
Third, build up the connections between the new one and the ones before and after it.
`*(n->pprev)` is the pointer to the next node. Before, it was node next but now it is n.
The first two lines are for node 'n'.
The third line is for the node 'next'.
The fourth line is for the node ahead of n.
There four lines connect the whole list together.